# Laravel 5.4 ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, how?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, laravel, migration

Please help me to understand how to do this in Laravel 5.4. Can't google this.

```
CREATE TABLE t1 (
  dt DATETIME DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
);
```

This is not working:

```
$table->dateTime('dt')
        ->default(DB::raw('CURRENT_TIMESTAMP'))
        ->onUpdate(DB::raw('CURRENT_TIMESTAMP'));
```

The question is about THIS PART:

```
ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
```

**SOLVED:**

Well, solution was simple :/

```
$table->dateTime('updated')
        ->default(DB::raw('CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP'))
```